# Woo coding - single product page issues

Tags: html, woocommerce, product, disable

apologies if this is completely the wrong place for posting but I'm a little bit lost...

I'm developing a WP and Woo commerce page that will have a HUGE number of images that when you click on each one it will pop up and you can demo it (this bit works at the moment)

But... once it's been added to the basket I want the 'add to cart' button to show as 'added' or something similar and for you not to be able to do anything else with it - at present if you try and click on the item again it shows the single product page (which I DO NOT want) as it screws up the whole point of the page I'm building.

Im a total novice with coding and just hash things together from google searches until something works... or breaks.

Is there anyone out there who can point me in the direction of how to achieve what I want or who might be interested in helping to fix my issues directly?

Thanks so much!

Comment: This question might be better asked on the WP stack https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks so much @MarkCarpenterJr - I'll pop it over there now

Comment: You're Welcome! Please drop a link here when you do.